# Slidetoggle am I missing something

Tags: jquery

I have this [page](http://posnation.com/pre_config/step4/Salon/1) and when i click the header like "Computers" or any of the others the items below need to slide up and down

I have this structure

```
    <div class="title-box box-active">
    <div class="line">
        <div class="text left">
            <p>(1) Software</p>
        </div>
        <div class="price right">
            <p>500.00</p>
        </div>
        <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-t"></div>
    <div class="item-c">
        <div class="line last">
            <input type="text" class="field left" value="1" />
            <div class="text left">
                <p>Aldelo</p>
            </div>
            <div class="price left">
                <p>450.00</p>
            </div>
            <a href="#" class="close right"></a>
            <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-b"></div>
</div>
```

but this is not working and I cant figure out why

```
$('.title-box').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().next('.line').slideToggle();
return false;
});
```

Comment: Where in the html is the `$('.title-box')` that you refer to in your jQuery?

Comment: if you click on the page and view source you can see the headings that have the category names that I need to click on and the items below slide up and down and I fixed my question

Comment: what you showed is not complete coding. Can you show complete coding?

Comment: go to the link i posted and view source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to get the `.line` element to slide, it is a `child` of `.title-box`, so try this:

```
$('.title-box').click(function() {
    $(this).children('.line').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```

In the callback, `this` refers to the `.title-box`. So since `.line` is a direct child of `.title-box`, you need to use `.children('.line')` to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Given the structure of the page, I believe this is the code you need

```
$('.title-box').click(function() {
    $(this).next('.item').slideToggle();
    return false;
});
```